Create a custom formula for conditional formatting that compares values in 4 columns to determine if they are a % higher than the original value
I am working with a dataset where participants were tested on a performance measure at various periods of time. When cleaning the data, we are looking to ensure that a more technical formula set up by the team upstream is properly capturing all cases where the participant improved on their original score by 26% or more.
There are 4 periods of testing after the original test, so I am attempting to use a custom formula for conditional formatting that will visually highlight every test score in Columns C through F that are 26% higher than the original score located in Column B for that participant.
Since the scores are formatted as percentages in Google sheets (custom number format is 0%), I am struggling to make sense of how to do the comparison in the conditional formatting's custom formula area. I also am having trouble making sense of absolute references & if I need to lock in the column when setting up the formula or not.
Here is some dummy data I drafted:



participant
Score 1
Score 2
Score 3
Score 4
Score 5




A
20%
70%
70%
35%
47%


B
83%
90%
90%
100%



C
43%
57%
60%

54%


D
10%
13%
24%
33%
39%


E
63%
70%
90%
85%
100%


F
53%
60%


80%



I've tried a few custom formulas conditional formatting - all of them seem to highlight test scores without any rhyme or reason.
I have applied the formulas to one column at a time so far (Column C) rather than conditionally formatting all of Columns C-F in one go, but I would welcome a solution that encompasses that as well
=C2>=(B2+0.26)
=C2>=($B2+0.26)

I am also a bit confused by the option to use "Greater than or equal to" instead of Custom Formula. When I use this option and tried to do a similar thing (i.e. applying the conditional formatting to Column C, then inputting:
=B2+0.26
=$B2+0.26


It still creates an unclear and inconsistent pattern of values.

Can you share a screenshot showcasing your ideal expected output (by highlighting manually)?! your formula =C2>=($B2+0.26) should work provided you've given the range setting as C2:F within the conditional formatting rules.

You can use the following custom formula for conditional formatting:
=C2>=($B2 + ($B2/100)*26)

Please also select the range to which it needs to apply as "C2:F7".
